# Macbook Pro 2017 with 2 thunderbolt ports with triple monitor setup

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I currently have a macbook pro with 2 thunderbolt 3 ports and integrated graphic card and a [belkin dock](https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U095/) that I use for work, but can't get work done with just 1 monitor.
I have a triple 1080p monitor setup at home that uses VGA and/or HDMI and was wondering if there is anyway I can use all 3 monitors with my laptop. Please keep in mind that although the dock has 2 thunderbolt ports one is used to connect to the macbook and the other I need to use for my yubikey. So in total I only have 1 more thunderbolt port free (the one from the macbook).
Thank you guys!

Displays: 3 x https://support.hp.com/au-en/document/c05415696

Yubikey: https://www.yubico.com/product/yubikey-5c/

Comment: Please detail exactly which monitor model you have, and also which model of Yubikey

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this setup working, you'll want to get the following:

- 2 x Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI cable
- 1 x DisplayPort to HDMI adapter-cable
- 1 x USB-A to USB-C adapter

You would connect the first monitor directly into the MacBook Pro using the Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI cable.

The second monitor connects to the dock's Thunderbolt 3 connector using the Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI cable.

The third monitor connects to the dock's DisplayPort connector using the DisplayPort to HDMI adapter-cable.

The YubiKey connects to one of the dock's USB ports using the USB-A to USB-C adapter.

Example products:

Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI cable:
[https://www.amazon.com/uni-Thunderbolt-Compatible-MacBook-Pixelbook/dp/B075V5JK36](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075V5JK36)

DisplayPort to HDMI adapter-cable:
[https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-DisplayPort-HDMI-Cable-Feet/dp/B015OW3M1W](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B015OW3M1W)

USB-A to USB-C adapter:
[https://www.amazon.com/ARKTEK-Adapter-Convert-Samsung-Aluminum/dp/B075R95QM7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075R95QM7)

Comment: But will this work ? Since the dock is using a Thunderbolt port, which does not allow for daisy-chaining displays unless it is Thunderbolt 2 or the newest revision of DisplayPort (and mine are HDMI)
Also, thank you for answering!

Comment: You seem to have things mixed up. The dock is not using Thunderbolt (as in the original Thunderbolt). It use Thunderbolt 3. Thunderbolt 3 does allow for daisy-chains containing displays. And yes, it does work. I have a Thunderbolt 3 dock and use the DisplayPort as well as the Thunderbolt 3 ports for displays.

Comment: I see, and both displays you use are also hdmi displays?

Comment: Nope... it’s rare to see HDMI only monitors these days. I would prefer DisplayPort always.